# cachegrind counts do not reflect real performance

Tags: optimization, valgrind, cachegrind

Two versions of the same algorithm yield different total instruction fetch counts and cycle estimations under valgrind/cachegrind. The difference is about 25%. Process timing, however, is very similar (it is actually shorter for the cachegrind-slow version):

- **version 1:**

  ```
  Ir:     146,328,018,245
  CEst:   152,553,736,055
  timing: 17.93 s
  ```
- **version 2:**

  ```
  Ir:     185,221,836,610
  CEst:   197,531,381,950
  timing: 17.53 s
  ```

Is this behaviour expected? How can I learn more about why version 1 is slower?

Comment: Are you measuring the time of the cachegrind run, or of a "real" (you know what I mean) run?

Comment: @delnan, I'm measuring the real execution time using the `time` `bash` builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the inconsistency is due to the different compiler options used for the cachegrind runs and for the timing runs. In particular, I had disabled function inlining for the cachegrind runs (so that I could get meaningful per-function counts).